# Embed an OpenCV Image

Tags: c++, opencv

This might seem quite weird, but I'd like to **embed a PGM image in my source code**.

I've tried to create an array of bytes but when I display it, with the very same parameters I find in the original file, the image seems corrupted. Of course, the original is ok.

This is what I've tried:

```
unsigned char s1_1_pgm[10318] = {
    0x50, 0x35, 0x0a, //...
};

cv::Mat n(cv::imread("1.pgm"));
cv::Mat m(cv::Size(92, 112), 16, s1_1_pgm, 276);

std::cout << "CHR " << m.empty() << " type " << m.type() << " step " << m.step << " size " << m.size().width << " x " << m.size().height << std::endl;
std::cout << "PGM " << n.empty() << " type " << n.type() << " step " << n.step << " size " << n.size().width << " x " << n.size().height << std::endl;

imshow("hello", m);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

The output is obviously this:

```
CHR 0 type 16 step 276 size 92 x 112
PGM 0 type 16 step 276 size 92 x 112
```

I am completely new to OpenCV, so I might have done something really stupid.

What is the best way to embed an image in an OpenCV source code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you are using numbers directly to mimic what opencv loaded image. This means that you are putting the step, size and type manually, without knowing what they mean.

OpenCV by default opens an image in the `RGB` colorspace (but loads it as `BGR`). This is represented as a matrix of type `CV_8UC3` -> C3 is 3 channels and 8U is unsigned char (8 bit size).

276 is correct for this case, where you have 3 channels, but not for a greyscale image. 276 is the step size, how to get this number, easy:

```
int size = 1;
// use any way to get the size of the type used, either
// manually or maybe sizeof function.
int cols = 92;
int channels  = 1;  
int step = cols * size * channels;
```

In the case of a colored image, or at least one in the BGR colorspace, you will need a step of 276 (92 x 1 x 3). Also, the array will be organized in the following way:

```
 B_1 G_1 R_1 B_2 G_2 R_2 .... B_n G_n R_n
```

This means that each pixel needs 3 spaces of your array (3 uchar values), if you have the data in greyscale, then it will take 3 values to show one pixel, which will look like garbage to the human eye :)

To fix this problem just change

```
cv::Mat m(cv::Size(92, 112), 16, s1_1_pgm, 276);
```

to:

```
cv::Mat m(cv::Size(92, 112), CV_8U, s1_1_pgm, 92);
```

There is also another problem.... your data is the wrong size... For an image of 92 columns and 112 rows in greyscale, you will need an uchar array of 10304 values, but you are using one of 10318 values. you have some extra values somewhere.... judging by your comment, i think at the beginning.

Comment: Quite there! The image I see is the original *shifted to the right*. Since it's a face, I see two adjacent ears to the left of the image.

Comment: @senseiwa I updated the answer to give a better explanation of some things. Also, I think that you got some extra bytes in your array.... can you try removing 14 values at the beginning?

Comment: @api55 indeed 14 bytes is the PGM file header after which is the image data

Comment: @api55 Yes, with `cv::Mat m(cv::Size(92, 112), CV_8U, s1_1_pgm + 14, 92);` the image *seems* right! Is there a way I can verify this? The two images cannot be subtracted, I get a runtime exception `OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match` with a very simple code as `cv::Mat d = m.clone(); cv::subtract(n, m, d);`

Comment: @senseiwa well, as I told you before, one has 3 channels and the other one only 1.... you have 2 options, when loading the image pass a flag 0 to be loaded as `greyscale cv::Mat n(cv::imread("1.pgm, 0"));` or convert it to greyscale first, with the function [`cv::cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor)